# How to scope interceptor to a module in angular?

Tags: angular

Following is the interceptor in angular for replacing auth token.

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token: string = localStorage.get('token');
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

My app is structure like this:

```
--- app
   ---login // this is a routed module
   ---signup // this is a routed module
   ---main // this is a routed module
           ---profile // this is a routed child module
           ---items // this is a routed child module
```

Auth token will be available only after the login.

And I'm **setting the interceptor for main module (i.e. provided in main module)** (profile is where the user lands after login and sends requests based on received token)

But the issue here is that the interceptor is **not** getting called way before reaching the module.
So that when the profile component initialises and `OnInit()` I;m getting unauth response
& when I check the console I can see that the Authorization header is undefined.

How can I solve this?

**NOTE** I'm not providing it in `root` since this will spit out unauth error even before login. So I'm providing the interceptor only inside the `main.module.ts` file.

**NOTE** main module does not have any component with it. It is used only to register profile module and items module.

main module is getting loaded like this (from the root level):

```
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then((m) => m.MainModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition like this if token is available then add token otherwise request send without token

```
    @Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token: string = localStorage.get('token');

     if(token && token.length){

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

     }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: No . I can't do. a request without a token.

Comment: The issue is that the interceptor is not. getting called in my app.

Comment: I'm providing it inside the main.module.ts like this:  ```{
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },```

Comment: So to check if this is working I did a console log inside the intercept method of interceptor. But the truth is that no console output was shows. Seems like the interceptor is not getting called properly (or registered) I'm not sure...

Comment: I didn't want the interceptor to be global. I want it only inside the routed module called ```main.module.ts```

Comment: is it work on global scope , add in main module is it work ?

Comment: Yes, It should only start working after the main module is loaded. Cause when the app is loaded login screen appears, after authentication only the token gets generated and redirects to main module.